# url doesn't change in next page- web scraping

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to get some data from this page. when I navigate to the next page url doesn't change. here is my code for scraping the first page

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url="https://www.airyrooms.com/search?s=26-02-2018.28-02-2018.GEO.103859.Bandung"
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
g_data=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"styles-propertySearchResultDisplayContainer-1XpMp"})
i=0
for item in g_data:
    try:
        i=i+1
        print (item.contents[0].find_all("div",{"class": "styles-titlePopUp-17tHZ"})[0].text)#name 
        print (item.contents[0].find_all("span",{"class": "styles-propertyLocationLink-1iVPv"})[0].text)#location
        print (item.contents[0].find_all("span",{"class": "styles-lineThrough-xyCPH"})[0].text)# initial price 
        print (item.contents[0].find_all("div",{"class": "styles-value-3pvw_"})[1].text)# price after disount 
    except:
        pass
print(i)
```

I don't know how to get data from the other pages.